# Python, Canadian Address RegEx validation

Tags: python, regex, validation

Im trying to write a Python script that validates Canadian Addresses using RegEx.

For example this address is valid:

```
 " 123 4th Street, Toronto, Ontario, M1A 1A1 "
```

But this one is not valid:

```
 " 56 Winding Way, Thunder Bay, Ontario, D56 4A3"
```

I have tried many different combinations keeping the rules of Canadian Postal codes such as the last 6 alphanumeric bits cannot contain the letters (D,F,I,O,Q,U,W,Z) but all entries seem to come out as invalid. and I tried 
" ('^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$') " but still invalid

this is what I have so far

```
    import re


postalCode = " 123 4th Street, Toronto, Ontario, M1A 1A1 "

#read First Line
line = postalCode

#Validation Statement
test=re.compile('^\d{1}[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$')


if test.match(line) is not None:
    print 'Match found - valid Canadian address: ', line
else:
    print 'Error - no match - invalid Canadian address:', line
```

Comment: What are the rules you have to follow?

Comment: At least the postal code cannot have the letters, (D,F,I,O,Q,U,W,Z).... the last couple of numbers in the address

Comment: Seems offtopic - you need to go find a resource on Canadian address validation (link?). After that writing the regex should be simple. Close as offtopic?

Comment: There's got to be a lot more rules than that. Is this the only part you are having trouble with?

Comment: Are you only talking about **validating the basic postal code format**? Or checking whether it's actually a valid postal code? and **corresponds to that province and city/town?** e.g. is "Nowheresville, MB, X0X 0X0" valid?

Comment: basically but apparently the data input is taking into consideration the first part of the address and it doesn't concentrate on the last 6 digits

Comment: Ah ok you just need to add something to match everything before the postal code. You could use `.*`. Post your code, we need to see are you using re.match, re.search, re.findall?

Comment: Basically Im trying to make sure that the whole address is valid bur I honestly dont know how.

Comment: The first step is to determine _all_ the required rules; converting them into regular expressions is generally not too difficult once you have those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canadian postal codes can't contain the letters D, F, I, O, Q, or U, and cannot start with W or Z:

This will work for you:

```
import re

postalCode = " 123 4th Street, Toronto, Ontario, M1A 1A1 "
#read First Line
line = postalCode

if re.search("[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ] ?[0-9][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]", line):
    print 'Match found - valid Canadian address: ', line
else:
    print 'Error - no match - invalid Canadian address:', line
```

---

```
WRONG - 56 Winding Way, Thunder Bay, Ontario, D56 4A3
CORRECT - 123 4th Street, Toronto, Ontario, M1A 1A1
```

---

## Demo

https://ideone.com/OyVB9h

Comment: Thank you very Much.... I have been spending the lasr week trying to figure it out.

Comment: why `re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL`?   Those do not seem correct here.

Comment: Copy paste from RegexBuddy, removed now. Tks for noticing that.

Answer (score 2):

It's been like this... forever:

```
/[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] ?[0-9][A-Z][0-9]/
```

If you want to restrict the first letter to only valid first letters then that's fine, but the rest is too complex to vary from that very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d
```

Maybe it will work :D